# How to create a class that calls different functions from different activities

Tags: java, android

I want to create a general helper class that contains a method that can be used by various java files in my project.
However, I'd like that method to be slightly different for each java file.

For example in Activity1, there's a function I wrote `func1()` that I'd like to be called from that helper method, but in Activity2, I'd like `func2()` to be called from that helper method.
`func1()` isn't defined in Activity2 and `func2()` isn't defined in Activity1.

Is there a way to say "if this helper method is called in Activity1 call `func1()`, else call `func2()`?
Obviously

```
helperClass {
    method() {
        if(Activity1) {
            func1();
        } else { 
            func2();
        }
    }
}
```

won't work because Activity1 won't recognize func2() and vice versa.

Another complication is that `func1()` and `func2()` both use fields defined in Activity1 and Activity2 respectively.

What's the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: Not sure if that's somehow connected your question yet first lgtfy result.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204987/calling-function-from-another-activity

Comment: I think is necessary to know what will do the helper class because maybe the approach is wrong, but a solution could be create an Interface: YourHelperInterface { doSomething() } and differents Helper class to implement the interface, for example, HelperCaseOne, HelperCaseN... and if you use some dependency injector, inject an object of interface type, for example with dagger: @Inject YourHelperInterface yourHelper and use the named tag.  This approach fulfill the Open Close principle (SOLID)... but maybe with more information we could help you better