# How can you call a method of an activity from another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my first activity

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    }

    public void addNumbers() {
        ////
    }

}


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }

     // I need to call addNumbers() from here
}
```

I have tried instantiating FirstActivity in SecondActivity like so but I get an error. And I also heard its not the best practice to instantiate the whole activity.

```
FirstActivity firstActivity = new FirstActivity();
firstActivity.addNumbers();
```

Comment: Short answer: if your method can be used independent of any particular activity, then put it in its own, separate class.  Then EITHER activity can instantiate their own, SEPARATE instances of that class whenever they want.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of calling method in second activity, create a separate public class e.g. `Functions.java`, and implement it as

```java
public class Functions {
    public void addNumbers() {
        ////
    }
}
```

Now in your second activity where you want to call the method

```java
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        // Calling addNumbers() from here
        new Functions().addNumbers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put the mathematical operations in a repository and, if necessary, find the instance of that repository each time by calling its instance.
You can use these codes.

**First Make this Repository**

```java
public class CalculatorRepository {
    private static CalculatorRepository calculatorRepository = null;

    private CalculatorRepository() {

    }

    public static CalculatorRepository getInstance() {
        if (calculatorRepository == null) {
            synchronized (CalculatorRepository.class) {
                if (calculatorRepository == null) {
                    calculatorRepository = new CalculatorRepository();
                }
            }
        }
        return calculatorRepository;
    }

    public int AddFunction(int number1, int number2) {
        try {   // for  better handler (Optional)
            return number1 + number2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //  another function
    //  .
    //  .
    //  .
}
```

**Second Call Method**

Now you can easily use other methods inside by calling this class

```
int result = CalculatorRepository.getInstance().AddFunction(nmuber1,nmunber2);
```

Comment: I agree with breaking it into a separate class, but making it a singleton is assuming too much.  It should either be all static functions, or it should be scoped appropriately for the app, which may or may not be a singleton.

Answer (score -1):

Add the static keyword to your shared methods

```
public static void addNumbers()
```

Then use:

```
FirstActivity.addNumbers();
```

For more details check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21205038/14280831)

Comment: This can work, if there's no need to access instance variables.  But then it shouldn't be put on the Activity, it should go on another class.  Activity classes should all be about interacting with the Android framework, not about business logic.

Comment: @GabeSechan End of the day, it answers his question as he can access the function in the activity class. It is not the exact answer but is a hack.

Comment: Our purpose here isn't to give an answer to his question, its to give good answers.  Hacks should be a last resort when nothing else works, it shouldn't be the first thing you suggest to someone.  Especially when the better answer is so easy to do.